# Google Cloud Storage - Direct upload with XMLHttpRequest causes "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"-error

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, xmlhttprequest, cors, google-cloud-storage

my following question makes use of: Java, GWT, jQuery, App Engine (GAE).

There's a lot of questions regarding the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"-header but nothing seems to be what I'm after.

I'm trying to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage using [POST Object](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/reference-methods#postobject). This works fine if I'm simply using a html-form to actually make the upload. But as soon as I'm trying to use the XMLHttpRequest to make the exact same request, I get the error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource". I have followed the [setup CORS for a bucket](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#Configuring-CORS-on-a-Bucket)-guide. My CORS xml-file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CorsConfig>
  <Cors>
    <Origins>
      <Origin>*</Origin>
    </Origins>
    <Methods>
      <Method>GET</Method>
      <Method>POST</Method>
      <Method>HEAD</Method>
      <Method>DELETE</Method>
      <Method>OPTIONS</Method>
    </Methods>
    <ResponseHeaders>
      <ResponseHeader>x-goog-meta-foo1</ResponseHeader>
    </ResponseHeaders>
    <MaxAgeSec>1800</MaxAgeSec>
  </Cors>
</CorsConfig>
```

So why am I using the XMLHttpRequest? It's because I want to be able to have upload-progression on my file uploads to the Google Cloud Storage (GCS). I'm not sure if I'm making some mistake somewhere or if it's even possible to have upload-progress when uploading to the GCS. But as far as I understand there should be no limitation on this, since the upload-progression isn't based on communication with the GCS (other then upload speed).

I've forcefully cleaned my cache, but that didn't help! :(

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I really don't like answering my own questions because it seems like I didn't do enough research before I ask. But I really did, I did try everything I could for 1.5 days before I asked this question.

The problem was one line in the CORS xml-file:

```
<ResponseHeader>x-goog-meta-foo1</ResponseHeader>
```

Should be replaced by:

```
<ResponseHeader>*</ResponseHeader>
```

I really didn't think this would make any difference because I assumed the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'-header would be sent as default, since that's why I'm making this setup and the [docs](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#Configuring-CORS-on-a-Bucket) doesn't mention anything about it. I did kinda understand that the `x-goog-meta-foo1` was an example, but not that it would break the settings if used (Google, please update the docs).

Comment: Answering your own questions is acceptable.. as long as you do the research first.. which you did.. :) So don't worry about it..

Comment: +1 - no problem with answering your own question, it might help others in the future

Comment: This was driving me crazy for almost 2 days now. You saved my day. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to thank my younger self for this answer, for helping me two years later with, once again, the same issue! :D